# Woocommerce Variation Dropdown Background Colour

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop running on my site, https://www.uproute.co.uk, and the product variation dropdown is showing white text on a white background. I don't know if this is due to the theme that I'm using or CSS that I have implemented. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Happy to answer questions or provide information. Any help is greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code to your css file or directly to the page in `<style></style>` tag:

```
.select2-results__option {
    color: black;
}
```

The `select2-results__option` is responsible for modifying the text and more in your Woo dropdown list

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you! ) If you can, please, vote up my answer )

Comment: Done, but being a noob it doesn't show on the public count. Thanks again though.